# Configure Public Key Auth with Amazon Data Pipeline, SFTP, and S3

Tags: amazon-s3, sftp, amazon-data-pipeline

From the following [Data Pipeline ShellCommandWith (S)FTP Sample](https://github.com/awslabs/data-pipeline-samples/tree/master/samples/ShellCommandWithFTP):

> The sample relies on having public key authentication configured to access the SFTP server.

1. How do I configure public key authentication so that my Amazon Data Pipeline's **ShellCommandActivity** can access an on-prem server via SFTP and upload files to S3?
2. What command do I put in my ShellCommandActivity to test if it can talk to my on-prem SFTP server?

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't want to expose your password in your pipeline definition, the sample assumes you set up passwordless ssh login for your ftp server.

You can learn more about that here: http://www.linuxproblem.org/art_9.html

Please make sure that is allowed in your organization's security rules or check with someone in your IT department if you are unsure.

If you are allowed and able to set that up, you can test it by running the sample.  It has an sftp command that gets executed as part of the ShellCommandActivity.